# Convert Decimal to decimal of a particular format?

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion

I am getting an error when I am trying to execute a stored procedure.

C# property - that I can't change :

```
private decimal? a;
public decimal? A
{
    get { return a; }
    set { a = value; }
}
```

C# DAC layer that I can change :

```
if (A.HasValue)
    dict.Add("A", A.Value);
else
    dict.Add("A", null);
```

In stored procedure input --> I can't change

```
@A decimal(6,0)
```

What is the best way to convert it without having exception and data loss? I need to do the same for `@B decimal(8,2)`

The database columns accepts nulls and decimal of above format.

Error I am getting:

> Error converting data type numeric to decimal

Comment: `dict.Add("A", A.HasValue.Value);` doesn't compile. I think you want to use `dict.Add("A", A.Value)`

Comment: `A.HasValue.Value`, what? Why doesn't `dict.Add("A", A)` not simply work? As you've written you're not doing any special handling for `null` anyway.

Comment: @TimSchmelter ,Thanks , Is there any way to format the input decimal from c# code

Comment: @Rahul Chowdhury you need to re-write this question and provide more information in order for people to help you. Right now this question makes no sense. It is entirely unclear what the dictionary you are mentioning has anything to do with the overall question.

Comment: @user469104 , thanks , I will rewrite it . this dictionary is adding sql parameters. here I want to format a decimal from c# code so there is no exception thrown from DB side , right now it seems the store proc are not getting the input in proper format

Comment: @RahulChowdhury there is no formatting per se for values of type decimal in C#, they are just numbers. If your limitation in SQL Server is decimal(6,0) then the only 'formatting' you could do would be to make sure you never pass a value greater than 999999 or smaller than -999999 and that you pass only a whole numbers. For decimal (8,2) you would need to ensure to not pass values greater than 999999.99 or smaller than -999999.99.

Answer (score 1):

It's never mentioned which version of the language you're using, so I'm going to assume C# 6. You can remove the if/else statement and just use a single statement `dict.Add("A", A?.Value)`. This is a Null Conditional Operator: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx.

As far as how to convert and not lose data... This is typically not possible. If you have a number with 3 digits precision and you want 2 digits of precision, there is rounding associated with that which means the numbers will always be off a little bit. If you want to convert a number from say, 3 decimal places to 2 decimal places, simply put your value in to `string.Format()` with the proper format specifier. If you want a number with no precision (a whole number), just take your decimal and store it in an integer type `int myWholeNumber = myDecimal;` or convert (probably safer) `int myWholeNumber = decimal.ConvertToInt32(myDecimal);`

To convert a string to a decimal, just use the parse method. `decimal myDecimal = decimal.Parse(myStringDecimalValue);`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Currently I am using c# 4.0 , I am using Math.Round() as of now, yes typically it's not possible to prevent data loss.As of now I changed my code like that dict.Add("A",Math.Round(A.Value,0)); for decimal(6,0)  and dict.Add("B",Math.Round(B.Value,2)); for decimal(8,2)..hope it works